# CAST array or struct as a string

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am loading my data to athena from json format using `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`. Currently, I specify objects and lists with `struct<...>` or `array<...>`, but the goal is to have them in a final parquet table as `varchar` or `string` type. So that I could have it still in a JSON format but with a string/varchar type.

Could you advise some good way to do it?

Casting to json and afterwards to varchar did not work for me:

```
 CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT cast(my_struct_col as varchar) my_struct_col FROM (
    SELECT cast(my_struct_col as JSON) my_struct_col FROM raw_table
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_format) to turn your json into varchar:

> `json_format(json)` → `varchar`
> Returns the JSON text serialized from the input JSON value. This is inverse function to `json_parse()`:

```sql
SELECT json_format(JSON '[1, 2, 3]'); -- '[1,2,3]'
SELECT json_format(JSON '"a"'); -- '"a"'
```

Note that [json representation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-to-json) for `ROW` in Presto is just an array  -Presto does not preserve the column names info:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST(ROW(123, 'abc', true) 
    AS ROW(v1 BIGINT, v2 VARCHAR, v3 BOOLEAN)) AS JSON); 
-- JSON '[123,"abc",true]'
```

This was [changed in Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-to-json) (Athena version 3 engine should be based on it):

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST(ROW(123, 'abc', true) AS
            ROW(v1 BIGINT, v2 VARCHAR, v3 BOOLEAN)) AS JSON);
-- JSON '{"v1":123,"v2":"abc","v3":true}'
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I first cast to JSON and then use json_format: `select json_format(cast(col1 as JSON)) as col1 from table`